# grep behaves strange in combination with inotifywait

Tags: bash, grep, inotify

I'm having a hard time understanding some sort of anomaly with grep return value.

As noted in the grep man page, the return value will be zero in case of a match and non-zero in case of no-match/error/etc.

In this code: (bash)

```
inotifywait -m ./logdir -e create -e moved_to |
  while read path action file; do
    if grep -a -q "String to match" "$path/$file"; then
      # do something  
    fi
  done
```

It returns non-zero when matched.

In this code: (bash)

```
search_file()
{
  if grep -a -q "String to match" "$1"; then
    # do something
  fi
}

inotifywait -m ./logdir -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
      search_file "$path/$file"
    done
```

It returns zero when matched.

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

**EDIT:**
Let me be clear once more: if I run the first code on a file that contains the string, the if statement is running. if i run the second code on the same file, the if statement fails and does not run.

Comment: _"it returns non-zero when matched"_  No, it doesn't.  Something else is going on.  Off the top of my head, one possibility is that, since you wait on the event `create` but not `close_write`, the file is still being written when the `grep` test is run.

Comment: How do you know what it returns? Are you saying that it only runs the body of the `if` statement in the latter case?

Comment: @john1024 - nothing else is going on. no errors (i checked also without -q)

Comment: @that other guy - i checked both $? and insert the result into a variable

Comment: @Nlandau So that we can help you further, show a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: only the former works. if i add ! (not) to the latter it works also.

Comment: let me clear once more: if I run the first code on a file that contains the string, the if statement is running. if i run the second code on the same file, the if statement fails and does not run

Comment: There is no reason why this should happen the way this (incomplete) example is currently presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I support [@John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024)'s conjecture that he wrote as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443581/grep-return-value-anomaly#comment64292742_38443581).

The "anomaly" is likely due to a slight timing difference between the two versions of your script. In case of a `create` event the file is initially empty, so `grep` will start scanning a partially written file. Calling `grep` through a function introduces a small delay, which increases the chances of the searched-for data to appear in the file by the time `grep` opens the file.

The solution to this race condition depends on a couple of assumptions/requirements:

- Can you assume that pre-existing files in the watched directory will not be modified?
- Do you want to identify every new matching file as soon as possible, or you can afford delaying its processing until it is closed?

Comment: Finally it works. As @john1024 suggested, a small sleep after the event from inotify solved the problem. I must do it like this because i cant wait for close_write (it is constantly being written to) and the create event is to soon. Thanks for the help!